# How to convert byte array to string by chunks?

Tags: java, android, string, arrays

In case if byte array is large then

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
int length = is.read(buffer);
is.close();
String content = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
```

may fail with `OutOfMemoryError` (likely because of memory fragmentation or lack of free successive bytes)

How to convert `byte[]` array to `String` by chunks in Java?

Comment: i see you are parsing a huge json data, then use `android.util.JsonReader`

Comment: @Taras why you need to use data in form of chunks for image or video uploading?

Comment: @pskink the issue is not connected with JSON parsing, it's just converting byte array to String

Comment: @Nisarg, not sure I understand your question

Comment: `"the issue is not connected with JSON parsing"` and yes, judging from `String json` it smells like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @pskink, updated code

Comment: you are calling `InputStream#read()` and ignoring the number of bytes it has read, what actually do you want to achieve? now i'm almost sure it is xy problem...

Comment: @pskink it's the sample code with intention to show a positive use-case and ease the reading. I don't understand how your concerns are related to OutOfMemoryError?

Answer (score 0):

1.Calculate minimum heap memory the app `minimum_heap_memory_in_bytes=maximum_heap_memory_in_bytes/(4 or >4)`

2.And read `ByteArray` in chunks from `PreviousByteCount` to `PreviousByteCount+minimum_heap_memory_in_bytes`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method, hope it'll help

```
public String getBase64FromByteArray(byte[] byteArray){
    String base64 = "";
    try{
        base64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return base64;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to this..

```
 public String getBinaryString()
 {        
      int nRead;
      InputStream inputStream = <your input stream>
      ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      byte[] data = new byte[16384];
      while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
            }
      buffer.flush();
      byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64((byte[])buffer.toByteArray());
      String binaryString = new String(encoded, "UTF-8");
      return binaryString;
 }
```